# Was Gandalf a regular visitor to the Shire prior to Bilbo's birthday party?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

In *The Fellowship of the Ring* (movie), Gandalf arrives at the Shire to much fanfare.  In particular, young children chase his wagon hoping to see some magic.  This would logically imply that Gandalf was well known in the Shire, since the children would be too young to remember him if he was not a regular visitor. However, the movie and the book differ somewhat. Is there canonical evidence **in the books** that Gandalf was indeed a regular enough visitor, or at least had been to the Shire very recently before the party?

Comment: Even if the Hobbit children hadn't seen Gandalf themselves it's not unreasonable to assume they'd heard tales of him.

Comment: ***Gandalf came by. Gandalf! If you had heard only a quarter of what I have heard about him, and I have only heard very little of all there is to hear, you would be prepared for any sort I of remarkable tale.** Tales and adventures sprouted up all over the place wherever he went, in the most extraordinary fashion*

Comment: ***He had not been down that way under The Hill for ages and ages, not since his friend the Old Took died, in fact, and the hobbits had almost forgotten what he looked like. He had been away over The Hill and across The Water on business of his own since they were all small hobbit-boys and hobbit-girls.*** - The Hobbit. Chapter One

Comment: Your question is extensively answered by the duplicate above. Both are asking why the kids knew of Gandalf and if he travelled there often.